# Python : Convert hex value : from big-endian to little endian and then to decimal

Tags: python, hex

I am reading a file and extracting the data from the file, I could able to fetch the ASCII data and integer data.

I am trying to convert 8 bytes of data from Big endian to Little endian and then to decimal value.

Input file has this data

> 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f

This value has to be converted to 0x3ff0000000000000, so that hex_to_double(0x3ff0000000000000) returns value 1.0

The code I am trying to convert the above value to little-endian and to decimal is

```
# Get the Scalar value
file.seek(0, 1)
byte = file.read(8)
hexadecimal = binascii.hexlify(byte)
hexaValue = byte.hex()
print(" hexadecimal 1 : %s"% struct.pack('<Q', int(hexadecimal, base=16)))


**# unable to convert the value to the int, so that it can be passed to **hex_to_double** function**

# wrote this function to convert the int value to decimal value
def hex_to_double(h):
    return struct.unpack('<d', struct.pack('<Q', h))[0]
```

Any suggestions shall be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is already in `base16`. So you should first convert it to binary format and then unpack to decimal like this:

```py
>>> data = binascii.unhexlify(b'000000000000f03f')
>>> data
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
>>> struct.unpack('<d', data)
(1.0,)
```

Comment: Wow !!. Thank you for this easy and simple way to do this. I tried pack, unpack and convert, but in vain. :)

Comment: glad i was able to help